# clearInterval when the setInterval has finished the whole execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval, clearinterval

I have used clearInterval to stop the execution of setInterval when a function is called.

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setinterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
    ...
}
```

But the problem is the clearInterval doesn't wait that setInterval has finished to execute the entire code.... therefore I have an error.
How can I do this? (if it is possible)

Comment: Can you explain what it is you want to do? Calling `setInterval()` **schedules** an operation to take place a given amount of time in the future, over and over again at that time interval. How do you determine when the process is "finished"?

Comment: Why don't you use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`?

Comment: I'm tring... i don't know. Of course I need setInterval to do cycling operations.... but also I would stop them when myStopFunction is called and, as I said, I would stop setInterval any when it has finished.
Process finished, I mean that all the code inside the setInterval has to be executed before that it is stopped

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded, so `clearInterval()` won't run *while code is running* inside your interval function - it will run either before or after it.

Comment: I don't know why I have some errors.... maybe because I have many callbacks inside the `setInterval` about file writings...same file used in the code inside the `myStopFunction`.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense - you didn't mention the callbacks inside the setInterval. I've updated my answer to deal with this - basically put your post-stopping code into a callback as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to put your post-stopping code in a callback as well. You can check if this has been set before starting the next iteration, and then again inside your interval callbacks.

```
var myVar;
var stopCallback = null;
var processing = false;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setInterval(function(){
        processing = true; // don't let the finishStopping() code run yet
        alert("Hello");
        someOperationWithCallback(function() {
            /* inside your deepest level of callback */
            processing = false;
            if (stopCallback) finishStopping();
        });
    }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    stopCallback = function() {
        /* work to do after stopping */
    };
    if (!processing) finishStopping();
}

function finishStopping() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
    stopCallback();
    stopCallback = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setInterval(function(){
        console.log("Hello");
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }, 3000);
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: that would be a bit pointless - basically you've implemented `setTimeout`

Comment: You are right, but OP asked how to clear interval. You can see some useful pattern here.